# Generating random screenshot more than one with PHP and FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, screenshot

For the first time i have used the FFMPEG-PHP. I have followed this link :- "http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/12/how-to-run-execute-ffmpeg-with-php-on-windows-pc/"
 and it's working perfectly. Now i want to take screenshot from the video more than one. I already searched in google and find many solution. But, i am confused where i should change or add code.

It will be better for me if you kindly suggest me according to the above tutorial.

Please anyone help me to find my desirable output.

Thanks.....

Comment: Can you post the code here that you attempted?

Comment: All code as like as the below link tutorial..."http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/12/how-to-run-execute-ffmpeg-with-php-on-windows-pc"